# why use EOF to check if stdin buffer is cleared

Tags: c, stdin, eof

Say I have the following...

```
int main () {     
   char name [5] = "";
   char c;
   printf("Enter a name: ");
   fgets(name,5,stdin);
   while ((c = getchar()) != '\n');
   printf("Exiting...);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

The while loop will clean the stdin buffer but I have seen the loop done like this as well...

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

I am wondering if there is any difference between the 2??? Does testing for EOF make any difference?

Comment: Seeing as `fgets` reads the `newline` anyway, what is there left to read?

Comment: Nothing...wondering why I saw it online somewhere else?

Comment: Looking again, with `char name [5];` it is quite possible there *is* more to read, but you only need to clear the input if there is no `newline` at the end of `name`.

Comment: Also note, that `fgetc()` returns `int` not `char`.

Comment: @iharob, you mean `getchar()` instead of `fgetc()` :)

Comment: im forcing it so it only accepts 4 letters plus the string terminator....so say i was in a loop, the next name i'd enter, the stdin buffer would be clear and i wouldn't have to worry about it looping twice

Comment: getchar returns a char* or null ptr, not an int

Comment: @YusufJama the function is `int getchar();` so it returns `int`, perhaps you mean `fgets()`.

Comment: @YusufJama, nops: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm

Comment: @AlterMann `fgetc()` I am 100% sure. It returns `int` because `EOF` MUST be `int`.

Comment: @AlterMann sorry i mean fgets

Comment: @iharob, I agree with you, but I was pointing that OP is using `getchar`, not `fgetc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is any difference between the 2??? Does testing for EOF make any difference?

Yes, testing `c != EOF` makes a tremendous difference.  `getchar()` returns `EOF` in the event that it detects an error or end-of-file on the standard input.  Both of those are entirely possible.  Once `getchar()` returns `EOF`, it is likely to return `EOF` again on every subsequent call, so the version that does not test for `EOF` is at risk of going into an infinite loop.

Comment: how can you get EOF before a newline character? you would click enter...the newline char is before the EOF

Comment: Some editors, when you create a single line file, leave off the newline. Or, leave off the newline on the _final_ line. Technically, it's incorrect, but it happens, and a program should be able to deal with it.

Comment: @YusufJama, input could be redirected from a file that does not contain a newline.  Or the name entered could be less than five characters, in which case `fgets()` will read the newline.  There are other possibilities.

Comment: @CraigEstey so EOF is there incase of someone typing a one line file is what you are saying?

Comment: @YusufJama, EOF is there because you should code for *all* possibilities, not just the ones you think are likely.

Comment: @YusufJama: click enter? time to take a break :P

Comment: Form good habits while you are still working on simple programs such as you present.  If you cultivate a habit of sloppiness then it may be hard to break that habit later when it makes more of a difference.

Comment: Or using a broken editor. Or, IIRC, and I can't remember, specifically, which one, but an OS allows the last line to _not_ have newline. The file could have been imported/converted incorrectly from such a file. Also, remember, EOF is also for _error_, which could occur on _any_ char. Or, a program that creates the file does `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) fputc(...)` and then `fputc('\n')` but the programmer forgets to do the newline.