# Cleaning stdin buffer issue

Tags: c

Say I have the following piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char choice;
    char name[5] = "";
    do {
        printf("a = new name or anything else to quit\nChoice: ");
        choice = getchar();
        //not doing any error handling....assuming you only click 'a'
        switch (choice) {
            case 'a':
                getchar();
                printf("Enter a name which is 4 characters or less: ");
                fgets(name, 5, stdin);
                printf("Name: %s\n", name);
                char c;
                while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
                printf("%c", c);
                c = '\0';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    } while (choice == 'a');
    printf("Ending.....press enter now");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

What I am try to test here is clearing buffer when I have more than 4 characters typed into. It works fine whenever I have a name which is 4 chars or more, however when I hit 3 chars or less, the problem becomes the while loop. It expects a getchar() from the stdin buffer, however this is empty. What way is there to work around this issue?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but getchar() returns int, not char. You seem to be looking for newline after getting at most 5 characters, which seems ok, but I would use fgetc instead of getchar(), just because you're using fgets, and if for some reason getchar() doesn't use same buffer as fgets(), then all bets are off.  Also, I think fgets doesn't have to null terminate the string, so you may want to pass 4 instead of 5 in there, and then set name[4]='\0'; right after.   This might help you a bit, or you may want to rephrase the question.

Comment: I type the name "abc" for example.....what is stored in name[3] is going to be '\n'. Now since there is nothing in the buffer at this point, the while loop will getchar() from an empty buffer, meaning I am stuck there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `name` contains a newline character.  If it does, there's nothing in the buffer and you don't need to flush it.

```
    fgets(name, 5, stdin);
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    if (strchr(name, '\n') == NULL) {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    }
```

Comment: ahhhh this will work....if the string doesn't contains '\n', then i know it is in the buffer!

Answer (score 1):

We already discussed this in passing in the commentary on [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667600/2402272).  If there is room for it in the buffer, `fgets()` will consume the terminating newline, placing it in the buffer.  You can determine whether it has done so by looking for a newline in the buffer.  If you find one, then

1. You probably want to remove it -- by replacing it with `'\0'`, for example.
2. You should avoid trying to drain the tail of the input line, because the stream has already advanced to the next line.

Comment: im saying what if the name is 'ab\n'....fgets won't put that newline char in the buffer...it stays as name[2]. The response before yours is what i was looking for

Comment: @YusufJama, dbush's answer says exactly the same thing as mine.  By all means, however, if you prefer his then that's the one you should accept.

Comment: In your [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667485/why-use-eof-to-check-if-stdin-buffer-is-cleared) you were advised that if the input is short enough, the `newline` will be in the input string. Then there is nothing in the buffer to clear, but only if the `newline` is not present in the entry. Please read the man page for each of the functions you use, before asking how they work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the result of `fgets()`.  Unless code does so, using the contents of `name` may be undefined behavior.  Avoid magic numbers: uses `sizeof name`.

   ```
           // fgets(name, 5, stdin);
           if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
   ```
2. Look for a *potential* `'\n'` in `name[]`.

   ```
           char *eol = strchr(name, '\n');
   ```
3. If one is found, overwrite with the null character, else consume the rest of the line

   ```
           if (eol) {
             *eol = '\0';
           } else {
             int ch;
             while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
           }
   ```
4. Print `name[]`

   ```
           printf("Name: %s\n", name);
   ```